# Does not recognize @bind, web application asp.net mvc,

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

- I was doing some tutorials in asp,net mvc.
- Link of tutorials [Web Apps can’t really do *that*, can they? - Steve Sanderson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MiLAE6HMr10&t=2263s)
- I stuck with this error the system Does not recognize @bind.
- I was researched everywhere in the internet got nothing.
- i'm new with asp.net.

Source Code [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X7OrbzfsdGaq17cbYfEXc5UvBXzN2uH9/view)

Please find image Down and Help me,
thanks.

here is my code i working with it:

```
<h4>(@ToDoItems.Count)</h4>

<ul>
   @foreach (var item in ToDoItems)
   {
       <li>@item.Text</li>
   }
</ul>

err here-> <input @bind(nextItem) placeholder="Type Here..."/>
err here-> <button @onclick(AddItem)>Add item</button>

@functions {
  string nextItem;
  List<ToDoItem> ToDoItems = new List<ToDoItem>();

  void AddItem()
  {
     ToDoItems.Add(new ToDoItem { Text = nextItem });
     nextItem = null;
  } 
  class ToDoItem
  {
     public string Text { get; set; }
     public bool IsDone { get; set; }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What you are looking at is a demo of the Blazor project which is still an experimental project at this time. Are you trying to build a Blazor app?

Comment: yes this what i looking for but don't know is not Issued yet, i'm new with asp when i see the demo for Blazor looks incredible.

Comment: as far as I know there is no built in support for Blazor in Visual Studio, you have to clone the repo and work from the template/sample.

Comment: this is my project i try make https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X7OrbzfsdGaq17cbYfEXc5UvBXzN2uH9/view

Comment: I'm not going to download your project. Did you [clone the repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor)?

Comment: Now i'm using Blazor project in Visual Studio Preview and u can try https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/03/22/get-started-building-net-web-apps-in-the-browser-with-blazor/

Comment: Yes, I saw the preview announcement. Are you saying it still doesn't recognize @bind?

Comment: no, now its working fine and i like Blazor. thank you.
i just put the link for who want try Blazor Project.